# Sum of bounded and unbounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Is there a Banach space $X$,  $S$ an unbounded operator defined on a dense subspace $D$ of $X$ and a bounded operator $T$ on $X$ such that

$$S+T|_D$$

is bounded? What if $T$ is assumed to be compact?

Comment: General fact: If $G$ is a group, $H \le G$ is a subgroup, $h \in H$, and $k \notin H$, then $kh, hk \notin H$.  The set of all linear operators on $D$ is an (abelian) group under addition, and the bounded operators are a subgroup.  So are the compact operators.  This is also the fact that an even number plus an odd number is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the difference of two bounded operators is bounded.